# Copying Range After Last Row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the entire range from **"Leads"** sheet after the last row of **"TempDataNew"**

```
If Sheets("Leads").Range("A1") <> "" Then
                Set rngSource = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                lastrowdyn = rngSource.Rows.Count

                If lastrowdyn > 0 Then
                    Sheets("Leads").Range("A:A").Copy
                    Sheets("TempDataNew").Range ("A" & x)
                    Set rngSource = Sheets("TempDataNew").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    x = lastrowdyn + 1
                End If
            End If
```

I am getting the **"Application Defined or Object Defined Error"** when the code is trying to paste. Any thoughts?

Comment: to get the lastRow use `lastrowdyn = Sheets("Leads").Cells(Sheets("Leads").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` , Question, where is the `Paste` line ?

Comment: @ShaiRado- the line followed by .copy. I have tried using Destination:= as well as .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want to copy to the bottom of the used range of `TempDataNew`, not `Leads`. So change this

```
Set rngSource = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

to this

```
Set rngSourceTempDatNew = Sheets("TempDatNew").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
lastrowdynTempDatNew = rngSourceTempDatNew.Rows.Count
```

Also, I'm guessing you really don't want or need to copy the entire column A of `Leads`. So this needs to be changed.

```
Sheets("Leads").Range("A:A").Copy
```

or that is exactly what you'll end up doing. May I recommend also finding the last row of the used range in column A of `Leads` as you want to do for `TempDatNew`. Maybe something like

```
Set rngSourceLeads = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Now just copying from the range in `Leads` to the right spot in `TempDatNew` can be done with something like this

```
rngSourceLeads.Copy _ 
destination:=Worksheets("TempDatNew").Range("A" & lastrowdynTempDatNew + 1)
```

I can't exactly tell why you are storing the last row plus one to `x`, but my current thinking is that it isn't needed for your purposes. Every time this code is ran, it will update the last row of `TempDatNew` for you and you just simply paste in the row after that.

So, all together you have something more succinct and accurate with

```
If Sheets("Leads").Range("A1") <> "" Then
    Set rngSourceTempDatNew = Sheets("TempDatNew").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    lastrowdynTempDatNew = rngSourceTempDatNew.Rows.Count
    Set rngSourceLeads = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rngSourceLeads.Copy destination:=Worksheets("TempDatNew").Range("A" & lastrowdynTempDatNew + 1)
End If
```

**EDIT**
If you only want to copy column A in "Leads" change this

```
Set rngSourceLeads = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

to this

```
lastrowdynLeads = Sheets("Leads").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlup).Row
Set rngSourceLeads = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1:A" & lastrowdynLeads)
```

This assumes you have no data below row 65000 in column A in sheet "Leads".

Comment: Works like a charm, well... almost. The code you provided copies the entire range from Sheet "Leads" and pastes it to "TempDataNew". What I really want is to copy the contents of Column 1 and paste it after the last row of column 1 in Sheet "TempDataNew". Any thoughts?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to insert a column after column 1 in "Leads". But I don't know if that is acceptable in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what x is before you begin running the code. I have added a line to give x a value. The way you had it, excel was evaluating x to be 0, thus resulting in a range called `Range("A0")`... that doesn't exist.

```
If Sheets("Leads").Range("A1") <> "" Then
    Set rngSource = Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    lastrowdyn = rngSource.Rows.Count
    x = 1 'Whatever integer it is supposed to start at
    If lastrowdyn > 0 Then
        Sheets("Leads").Range("A:A").Copy
        Sheets("TempDataNew").Range ("A" & x)
        Set rngSource = Sheets("TempDataNew").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        x = lastrowdyn + 1
    End If
End If
```

Comment: just updated the code a bit to reflect that you want the value of x to increase with each iteration

Comment: x=2 before this loop began. So, it shows "A2". But still paste wont work.

Comment: what is the error message now? still the same? and if so on what line does it stop?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem you were originally experiencing in your code... Your first IF statement says `If Sheets("Leads").Range("A1") <> "" Then`. Your referencing a range object, and comparing it to a value. Your error should go away if you use `Sheets("Leads").Range("A1").Value <> ""`.

I'm not sure why you want to use `.CurrentRegion` if you're only working with a single column (I'm also not the most versed in VBA logic) but if you're just trying to find the last row, you could use something like this:

```
Dim Leads, TempDataNew as Worksheet
Set Leads = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Leads")
Set TempDataNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempDataNew")

    lastrowdyn = Leads.Cells(Leads.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Leads.Range("A1").Value <> "" And lastrowdyn > 0 Then
        Leads.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=TempDataNew.Range("A" & x)
        x = lastrowdyn + 1
    End If
```

Comment: Due to reputation being low, I cant comment on the rohrl77's answer, but if x is to be a counter of sorts, you'd never want to initialize it in your IF statement.

Comment: Looking at my code again, I see what seems off to me about it.. why do you want a second IF statement seeded that checks for essentially the same thing? Unless A1 is some type of trigger cell that will only have a value if you want the whole column copied..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim wsLeads As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRowNew As Long, lRows As Long, iColumns As Integer

    Set wsLeads = Worksheets("Leads")
    Set wsTemp = Worksheets("TempDataNew")

    lLastRowNew = wsTemp.UsedRange.Rows(wsTemp.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    lRows = wsLeads.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iColumns = wsLeads.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    If wsLeads.Range("A1").Value <> "" And lRows > 0 Then
        wsTemp.Cells(lLastRowNew + 1, 1).Resize(lRows, iColumns).Value = wsLeads.UsedRange.Value
    End If
End Sub
```